# How Can i change apache isis default login page to my own custom login page?

Tags: apache, isis

Apache ISIS has default login page. but how can i chang with my own login page?
and how can i create my own **QuickStartApplication.java** class.

Comment: that tag is for a different product.  I don't have the SO reputation to create a new one 'apache-isis' one, though... perhaps someone else might?

Answer (score 1):

Until Isis becomes a little better known, you'd probably be better off asking this question on the Isis mailing list.

The short answer though is to register a different sign in page through the PageRegistrySpi.  The easiest way is probably to install a different implementation of PageClassRegistry, by overriding the IsisWicketModule [1] (guice bootstrapping).  The IsisWicketModule itself is specified by overriding the appropriate hook in IsisWicketApplication [2].

Head over to the mailing list for more info.

[1] https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/5ca7bf71df93921d56702df739973cd67c5223f7/component/viewer/wicket/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/viewer/wicket/viewer/IsisWicketModule.java

[2] https://github.com/apache/isis/blob/77aa56878f60bda6b21daa4300e5eb6dd914cce1/component/viewer/wicket/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/isis/viewer/wicket/viewer/IsisWicketApplication.java#L273

Comment: Thanx Dan, i am using shiro security in apache isis. currenty i am using shiro.ini file with static username and password. Is there any way to login with my database table with shiro security in APACHE ISIS without LDAP. i am using mysql database.

Comment: I've edited your tags to remove Isis2, which is a tag for isis2.codeplex.com and not related to the Apache project.

Comment: so can any one create APACHE ISIS tag, i am new in stackoverflow.

Comment: LOL this question reads so differently now that ISIS has a whole new meaning,